# ROS2 rclcpp serialization : Cannot deserialize message of type geometry_msgs/msg/transform_stamped

Tags: ros, rosbag, rclcpp, serialization

I'm trying to plot the trajectory of a Crazyflie2 drone which is record on the /tf topic of a rosbag. I reused the code copied the code from this ROS2 tutorial (https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Tutorials/Advanced/Reading-From-A-Bag-File-CPP.html) and changed very little.
But when I try to run my code on the appropriate rosbag, I get this :

```
[INFO] [1698913142.799724306] [rosbag2_storage]: Opened database 'ros2_ws/bagfiles/tfbag/tfbag_0.db3' for READ_ONLY.

>>> [rcutils|error_handling.c:108] rcutils_set_error_state()
This error state is being overwritten:

  'Handle's typesupport identifier (rosidl_typesupport_cpp) is not supported by this library, at ./src/type_support_dispatch.hpp:111'

with this new error message:

  'Fast CDR exception deserializing message of type geometry_msgs::msg::dds_::TransformStamped_., at ./src/type_support_common.cpp:118'

rcutils_reset_error() should be called after error handling to avoid this.
<<<
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'rclcpp::exceptions::RCLError'
  what():  Failed to deserialize ROS message.: Fast CDR exception deserializing message of type geometry_msgs::msg::dds_::TransformStamped_., at ./src/type_support_common.cpp:118
[ros2run]: Aborted
```

I'm pretty new to ROS2 and rclcpp, so I'm lost. Can someone help me out with this ?

My code :

```
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>

#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "rclcpp/serialization.hpp"
#include "rosbag2_cpp/reader.hpp"
#include "geometry_msgs/msg/transform_stamped.hpp" //


using namespace std::chrono_literals;

class PlaybackNode : public rclcpp::Node
{
  public:
    PlaybackNode(const std::string & bag_filename)
    : Node("playback_node")
    {
      publisher_ = this->create_publisher<geometry_msgs::msg::TransformStamped>("/tf", 10);
      timer_ = this->create_wall_timer(
          100ms, std::bind(&PlaybackNode::timer_callback, this));

      reader_.open(bag_filename);
    }

  private:
    void timer_callback()
    {
      while (reader_.has_next()) {
        rosbag2_storage::SerializedBagMessageSharedPtr msg = reader_.read_next();

        if(msg->topic_name != "/tf"){
          continue;
        };

        rclcpp::SerializedMessage serialized_msg(*msg->serialized_data);
        geometry_msgs::msg::TransformStamped::SharedPtr ros_msg = std::make_shared<geometry_msgs::msg::TransformStamped>();
        serialization_.deserialize_message(&serialized_msg, ros_msg.get());
        publisher_->publish(*ros_msg);
        int timestamp = ros_msg->header.stamp.sec + 0.000000001*(ros_msg->header.stamp.nanosec);
        std::cout << "/tf [" << timestamp << "] : " << "(" << ros_msg->transform.translation.x 
                  << " ; " << ros_msg->transform.translation.y << " ; " << ros_msg->transform.translation.z << ")" << std::endl;
        break;
      }
    }

    rclcpp::TimerBase::SharedPtr timer_;
    rclcpp::Publisher<geometry_msgs::msg::TransformStamped>::SharedPtr publisher_;

    rclcpp::Serialization<geometry_msgs::msg::TransformStamped> serialization_;
    rosbag2_cpp::Reader reader_;
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  if (argc != 2) {
    std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <bag>" << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }

  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
  rclcpp::spin(std::make_shared<PlaybackNode>(argv[1]));
  rclcpp::shutdown();

  return 0;
}
```